# Trouble Extracting Complete Reviews and Ratings from Dynamic Pages

Tags: python, html, json, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape extract data from website:
https://www.kununu.com/de/adidas/kommentare

However, when i try to extract the entire HTML code via webdriver, some data is not extracted.

The missing data is contained in a  storage, but to this point i can also extract this successfully.
Therefore, i use two sources for processing the data (Soup and JSON).

However, the page is dynamic, so I have to click on "Read more reviews". The data I retrieve via soup is expanded. This is not the case for the JSON data. With my procedure, I still only get the first data up to the first "Read more reviews" button.

This is my approach so far

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

consent_accept_button(driver)

show_more_reviews(driver, 2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

JSON = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").text)

driver.quit()
```

Soup now contains all the reviews that could be collected by clicking "Read more reviews" twice (Depending on show_more_reviews). JSON does not, as it still only contains the first ten reviews.

Why is that? And how can i expand JSON to contain all data?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there URL?

Comment: Sure. URL is inside the description.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can use their Ajax API to load more reviews:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.kununu.com/de/adidas/kommentare"
api_url = "https://www.kununu.com/middlewares/profiles/de/adidas/{id_}/reviews"

params = {
    "fetchFactorScores": "0",
    "reviewType": "employees",
    "urlParams": "",
    "page": "1",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
id_ = soup.select_one('a[href*="/review/"]')["href"].split("/")[5]

for params["page"] in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    data = requests.get(api_url.format(id_=id_), params=params).json()
    for r in data["reviews"]:
        for t in r["texts"]:
            print(t["text"])
        print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Akkord arbeiten mit weniger MA.
Mehr Gehalt für die Mitarbeiter die sich jeden Tag den Abschluss ausreißen, damit die Sesselpuper sich nicht bewegen müsse
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schulung für Vorgesetzte
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kantine
Fehlende Transparenz, kein Respekt, kaum Fairness.<br/>Viel Ignoranz.
Transparenz, Respekt und Fairness gegenüber allen Mitarbeitenden.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
```